# How to pass db:Session object to celery task in fastapi

Tags: sqlalchemy, celery, fastapi, celery-task, json-serialization

This is the route from where I am calling the the celery task in fastapi project

```
@router.get("/")
    def read_bhav(
    db: Session = Depends(deps.get_db),
    skip: int = 0,
    limit: int = 100,
    current_user: models.User = Depends(deps.get_current_active_user),
) -> Any:

    """
    Retrieve bhavs.
    """
    y, d, m = (datetime.now().year, datetime.now().day - 3, datetime.now().month)
    if date(y, m, d).weekday() < 5:
        # celery_app.send_task("app.worker.bhav_copy", (date(y, m, d), db))
        bhav_copy.delay(date(y, m, d), db)
        print(db)
        return {'TEST': "Successfully added"}
    else:
        return {"FAIL": "No Stock data for Weekends"}
```

Here is my celery_app.py file were I am configuring my celery app

```
from celery import Celery

celery_app = Celery("worker", broker="amqp://guest@queue//")

celery_app.conf["CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER"] = "pickle" 
celery_app.conf["CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT"] = ["pickle"]  
celery_app.conf["CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER"] = "pickle"

celery_app.conf['CELERY_ROUTES'] = {"app.worker.test_celery": "main-queue"}
celery_app.conf['CELERY_ROUTES'] = {"app.worker.bhav_copy": "main-queue"}
```

You can see I have tried multiple ways to serialize this into json or something of sort

```
@celery_app.task(acks_late=True)
def bhav_copy(date: date, db) -> str:
    prices = get_price_list(dt=date)
    prices.columns = map(str.lower, prices.columns)

    price_in = []
    for i in range(1, prices.shape[0] + 1):
        price = prices[i - 1:i]
        v = price.values.reshape(13)
        price_in.append(dict(zip(price.columns, v)))
    crud.bhav.insert_bulk(db=db, bhav_in=price_in)
    return f"inserted stocks data"
```

Would really appreciate a solution which would work to solve this issue, currently with this code I am getting the following error from below

```
backend_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 350, in pickle_dumps
backend_1       |     return dumper(obj, protocol=pickle_protocol)
backend_1       | kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Can't pickle <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session'>: it's not the same object as sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session
```

Comment: You can't pickle an active SQL connection; instead, make your celery worker create its own connection to your SQL server.